# JQuery Ajax only work with synchronous Ajax call and no response for asynchronous Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I updated my app's phonegap from 0.9.3 to 2.2.0 and also jQuery from 1.4.4 to 1.6.4. I tested the apps on a few device.

- For Android 2.3 - the apps is working fine(able to do a ajax call with username and password).
- For Android 3.2 - Ajax call keep loading and wait response from server.
- For Android 4.0 - Ajax call keep loading and wait response from server.
- For Android 4.1.2 - Ajax call keep loading and wait response from server.

The app are currently using asynchronous call and not able to receive response from server.
I tested the app using synchronous call and everything is working fine(able to send and receive response form server). The reason why I wanted to use asynchronous call is that I don't want to lock up the screen.

Anyone have any idea regarding this problem ?

Below is my code.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                username: uname,
                password: pword,
                cache: false,
                data: null,
                url: baseURL+'weeks',
                dataType: "xml",
                contentType: "application/xml;charset=utf-8",
                crossDomain: false,
                error: loginErrorHandler,
                success: weeksParse,

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "," from the success function:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            username: uname,
            password: pword,
            cache: false,
            data: null,
            url: baseURL+'weeks',
            dataType: "xml",
            contentType: "application/xml;charset=utf-8",
            crossDomain: false,
            error: loginErrorHandler,
            success: weeksParse  // <----------- remove the last comma ','

        });
```

and see if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it's still not working. Not sure it would help or not but the readyState seen like stuck at 1 and doesn't update anymore.